# How to download a image using angular 8 application?

Tags: angular, codeigniter, angular8

I am using angular 8 as frontend and codeigniter as backend . I  have a table where there are multiple images which comes dynamically from the database with the different names . I want to download those images so that the user will be able to view the images separately . 
I tried doing in codeigniter

```
  $image = $this->uri->segment(3);
  $files = 'images/'.$image;
  force_download($image,$files);
```

This isnt working . Kindly suggest how this can be done in either angular or codeigniter

Comment: Please indicate what is not working,  for example what error you are getting or more specifically what the problem is.

Comment: you can't download multiple files at once - either you do it via multiple requests or you pack your files in a zip file.